# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+1}$ convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+1}$$ 
convergence by Cauchy theorem:

$$\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists N>0: \text{whenever}\ n>N,\ |a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{n+p}|<\varepsilon,\ p=1, 2, \cdots.$$

This is a homework in Calculus-1 course. I know it can be proved by such as root-test, etc. But how to prove it by Cauchy theorem? Thanks!

Comment: sum of geometric series!

Comment: What is Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: What "geometric series", @PA6OTA ?

Comment: I don't think it works since he asked to use that theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that $1/(2^n+1)$ is just a little smaller than $1/2^n$. Then
\begin{align}
|a_{n+1} + \cdots + a_{n+p}| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n+p}}.
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

**Hint**: the sum of the series on the right is
$$
\frac{1}{2^{n+p}}\Big(2^{p-1} + \cdots + 1\Big) = \frac{1}{2^{n+p}}\cdot(2^p-1)<\frac{1}{2^n}.
$$

Comment: Your answer is similar to @Don Antonio, yet it still not work well.

Comment: Then I didn't explain myself clearly. Can you tell me what you are confused about?

Comment: No. I meant your last post. But now you edited it, this is cool!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$\frac{1}{2^n +1}\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$$
so $$\sum\limits_{n=m}^{m+k}\frac{1}{2^n +1}\leq \sum\limits_{n=m}^{m+k}\frac{1}{2^n}
=\frac{1}{2^{m+k}}-\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}$$

Comment: This is not the way (the easiest one: comparison) the OP asked for.